# unable to click element using xpath and resource id

Tags: robotframework, appium-android

hi i am using robot framework for mobile app auotmation, i have used all posiible types of xpath and id but still i am unable to click an element in my mobile app.

attched relevant screenshot[screen shot of the app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNvzq.png)

please help in this.. i want to click on **get started** button but i am unable to do so. i have used the following it is not working

- Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  1 min  5 sec   Click Element  xpath=//*[@class='android.widget.TextView' and @index='0']
- Click Element  id=sr_get_started

Comment: Can you please include the image in the question and not refer to it as a link ad provide the HTML code that your xpath refers to.

Comment: What does "unable" mean? Why are you unable? Does robot crash? Does it pick the wrong element? Does it say it can't find the element? Does it say it finds the element but that it's disabled?

Comment: by unable i mean i am getting appium logs 'searching element via xpath' , but no response is returned from robot and appium server logs. i have tried al possible xpath's. is there any issue in finding element via xpath...because it is not even giving error that element not found